# Partial Update in Eleastic Search Document

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I just started exploring the elastic search and I stuck with a requirement in my project. I tried multiple thing but nothing worked for me. I have saved a sample document in elastic search index

```
"orderData": {
  "lines": [
    {
      "lineNbr": 1,
      "quantity": {
        "amount": 1,
        "uom": "EACH"
       },
      "weight": null,
      "Qty": null
    },
    {
      "lineNbr": 2,
      "quantity": {
        "amount": 1,
        "uom": "EACH"
       },
      "weight": null,
      "Qty": null
    }
 ]
}
```

Next time I want to update only some of the data in line nbr one but here the problem is I dont want to do fields wise update. I get full Line Nbr 1 json again something like

```
{
      "lineNbr": 1,
      "quantity": {
        "amount": 10,
        "uom": "EACH"
      },
      "weight": 5,
      "Qty": 5
}
```

But if I am performing update line nbr 2 tag is removed and only line nbr 1 tag is left with the updated data but I never wanted to touch line nbr 2
How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Could you post the query you've used for updating the document like what you've tried so far?

Comment: UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("index","type","id");updateRequest.doc(json);
client.update(updateRequest).get();

Comment: In the above comment json is the Line json that I wanted to update.

Comment: What language are you using for updating Elastic? Can you post the JSON query you're using to update?

Comment: I am using the Java. ANyways I tried this also .POST index/type/{id}/_update  
{
  "doc" : {
          "lineNbr": 1,
          "quantity": {
            "amount": 10,
            "uom": "EACH"
          }
  } 
}